# '/home/ruben/aokp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/iasl' missing while attempting to build AOKP version 7.1.2

Tags: android

This is what shows when i try to build aokp:

```
ninja: error: '/home/ruben/aokp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/iasl', needed by '/home/ruben/aokp/out/target/product/me176c/obj/FAKE/dsdt.hex_intermediates/dsdt.hex', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I would be glad if I could get some help.